# mysql search help comma seprated values

Tags: php, mysql

I'm fairly new to MySQL, php. I have a database that has a column Artists with some comma separated txt values, and some not. I know its not a proper way to store the data but its an imported table from another software I cannot change it. Here is my situation. In the we could have

```
|     Artist     |
  Meadows, Jason
  Jason, Meadows
  Meadwes Jason
     ..etc.
```

When the user inputs either Meadows or Jason  the query finds the variation but if the user inputs Jason meadows or Meadows jason the search comes up empty. I've searched and tries multiple combination with no success. I have even written a small php code to separate the comma separated values into two separate $Vars and tired joining the 2 with commas and spaces to add to the query as AND.

here is my code:

```
$SearchItem = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$SearchItem);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$DjID$Djdatabase` WHERE  ArtistName LIKE '%$SearchItem%' Or TrackName LIKE '%$SearchItem%'";
```

I wrote a php script to separate the user input into 2 separate variable example below:

php to separate the user input into 2 variables ex: user inputs Meadows, jason the output will be: $SearchItem! = Meadows and $searchItem2 = Jason or if Meadows is the input the output is $SearchItem! = Meadows $SearchItem2 = Meadows. This script also removes any spaces between Meadows and jason.

```
<?php

$var = explode(",", $SearchItem, 2);
if (array("0",$var)){
    trim($SearchItem1= $var[0]);
    if(array_key_exists("1",$var)){
        $SearchItem2=$var[1];
    $SearchItem2 = ltrim($SearchItem2);
    }
    else{
    $SearchItem2=$var[0];
    }
    }
    if($SearchItem == $var[0]){
        $var = explode(" ", $SearchItem, 2);
    if (array("0",$var)){
    trim($SearchItem1= $var[0]);
    if(array_key_exists("1",$var)){
        $SearchItem2=$var[1];
        $SearchItem2 = ltrim($SearchItem2);
        }
    else{
        $SearchItem2=$var[0];
        }
     }
}

?>
```

I have tried every combination of:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$DjID$Djdatabase` WHERE  ArtistName LIKE '%$SearchItem1$SearchItem2%' Or TrackName LIKE        
    '%$SearchItem1$SearchItem2%' ";        
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$DjID$Djdatabase` WHERE  ArtistName LIKE '%$SearchItem1,$SearchItem2%' Or TrackName LIKE 
    '%$SearchItem1,$SearchItem2%' ";
```

``
Note:  I also check in column TrackName as well incase the user has a really bad list. The search must not be case sensitive.

Any help would be greatly appreciated..Thanks in advance this site has been alot of help..Cheers!

Comment: Also, keep in mind that this is a suboptimal data structure. You can avoid tons of future problems by migrating your data to a normalized database layout

Comment: Nico thanks for taking the time to answer I tried SELECT * 
    FROM  `$DjID$Djdatabase`
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET('%$SearchItem%',ArtistName) > 0  It didn't work. But the again I had been at it for a long time. so it could have been typo. Unfortunately I cant change that data caus its imported from another software like that I have no control over it.

Comment: `its an imported table from another software I cannot change it`...well, you could transform it when you import it, if you wanted to. As long as you don't change the original source of the data, it wouldn't matter.

Comment: I've thought about it for future updates, however my skilla are limited being new at this. as well i have multiple existing databases of 300,000+ rows existing...oy

Comment: Links provided as duplicate answers (  @Barmar ) - do not answer this question. Here it is about matching values with the data that are - with or without comma as separator - with no particular fixed order - with some obvious misspelings. Links provided do not answer this.

Comment: Thanks for those who replied. I could not get suggested links to work so I wrote a concat script in php coupled with my php to split the comma seperated variables and voile she works like a dream.

Comment: @Drspl There is a solution using mysql only...